# Zero-width/invisible characters to force custom ordering

Tags: utf-8

What zero-width characters exist in UTF-8 that are not treated as spaces[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)? I am particularly interested in those which glyphs that do not render on major browsers: the not-found rectangle should never be shown.

There are many web services that order user entered data alphabetically (eg. Gmail's labels). I would like to use those invisible characters to enforce custom ordering.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) *Treated as spaces*: not removed by commonly used implementations of `trim` and similar. With the gmail example, `U+202F` (Narrow no-break space) is trimmed.

**Edit:** Only one invisible character should suffice. After all, they may be repeated without having an effect on the visual representation (assuming a lower code ascii text follows):

```
[char]Z on first position
[char][char]B on second position
[char][char][char]C on third position
```

Unfortunately, all characters I could think of are either trimmed right away or ignored by sort functions.

**Edit:** I've browsed through [all UTF-8 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) that seemed zero width / invisible and none worked as required. `U+0 - U+20`, `DEL`, Control chars, even symbols such as U+034F: `COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER (alias CGJ)`, all are treated properly and thus unusable for my purpose. I keep searching though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following ones:

```
U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE 
U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER  
U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
```

Comment: Unfortunately these are all treated as spaces. While not trimmed right away, they are ignored when the strings are sorted. I'm afraid the same goes for most invisible characters (also including those with the not-found rectangle, for example all `* digit zero` chars).